# Is it possible to use MPMediaPickerController to load audio files from library and save to document directory?

Tags: iphone, mpmediapickercontroller

Is it possible to use MPMediaPickerController to load audio files from library and save to document directory?

Welcome any comment.

Thanks

KS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have implement the MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate protocol's mediaPicker:didPickMediaItems: function.
I think, you could save the picked data there as you desire.

Comment: I stuck into same problem, I am still searching for it. If you've sample source or link available please share. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is a few months old, but iOS 4.0 and later do provide the ability to copy a song from the iPod library to your application's documents directory via the [AVAssetExportSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

There are a few drawbacks with AVAssetExportSession, so I would recommend that anyone wanting to import files without having to transcode them all to AAC have a look at [TSLibraryImport](https://bitbucket.org/artgillespie/tslibraryimport).

[AVAssetReader](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetReader_Class/Reference/Reference.html) can also be used if you're interested in directly accessing un-compressed linear PCM data without having to first copy the file and then using Core Audio to access the data.